# Magento: add a modified header.phtml to a copy of empty.phtml file for a custom module

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module for a landing page after default customer login, I'm using the blank template page : empty.phtml;

I want now to add to "empty.phtml" an edited version of footer and header.phtml, without editing the original versions of this files.

How can I do that ??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try put it to landing page's section into your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <your_landing_page>
    <reference name="header">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>your_module/header_file.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
...
```